# Google Advanced Image search - Appear in cc search

Tags: seo, google, images

How do I mark that my images are public domain and can appear in google images - advanced search with option "usage rights:free to use, share, or modify even commercially".

I want to mark my images so they appear in search results.

Answer (score 1):

Your images may appear in Google images whether you want them to or not. You can use an [image sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178636) to increase your chances. Use the `<image:license>` tag to link to your license to show those usage rights.

Comment: Does Google parse the license given in RDFa, too? (http://wiki.creativecommons.org/Web_Integration/HowTo)